# Knockout.js show / hide block visibility pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, knockout.js, dry

I have the **code duplication problem** in the next case. On my page I have a lot of blocks that I need to show / hide by clicking to link:

```
<div>
    <a data-bind="click: showHiddenFirst, visible: isVisibleFirst"href="#">Show first</a>
    <div data-bind="visible: !isVisibleFirst()" style="display:none">
        hidden content first
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a data-bind="click: showHiddenSecond, visible: isVisibleSecond"href="#">Show second</a>
    <div data-bind="visible: !isVisibleSecond()" style="display:none">
        hidden content second
    </div>
</div>
```

And my JS

```
var vm = function(){
    this.isVisibleFirst = ko.observable(true);

    this.showHiddenFirst = function(){
        this.isVisibleFirst(false)
    };

    this.isVisibleSecond = ko.observable(true);

    this.showHiddenSecond = function(){
        this.isVisibleSecond(false)
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Here is jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/sstude/brCT9/2/

**Question** is *how to avoid all this show / visible duplication*? Maybe I need some custom binding where I put id of my hidden block or smth. else? Any patterns that you can suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here was a thought at encapsulating this functionality completely in an observable for your specific scenario:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.clickVisible = {
    init: function(element) {
       var visible = ko.observable(true),
           opposite = ko.computed(function() { return !visible(); }),
           clickHandler = visible.bind(null, false);

        //apply bindings to anchor
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { click: clickHandler, visible: visible });

        var sibling = element.nextSibling;
        //find the div (as text nodes, etc. will show up in nextSibling)
        while (sibling && sibling.nodeType != 1) {
            sibling = sibling.nextSibling;   
        }        

        //apply bindings to div
        if (sibling) {
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(sibling, { visible: opposite });
        }
    }
};
```

It could be tweaked further, as necessary, if maybe the value passed into the binding should matter.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gCgy5/

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [**template**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) together with a separate model for the hidden elements:

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'hidden-template', data: first }"></div>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'hidden-template', data: second }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="hidden-template">
    <a data-bind="click: showHidden, visible: isVisible, text : linkText" href="#"></a>
    <div data-bind="visible: !isVisible(), html: content" style="display:none"></div>
</script>
```

**JS**

```
var hiddenModel = function(linkText, content) {
    this.linkText = linkText;
    this.content = content;
    this.isVisible = ko.observable(true);
    this.showHidden = function(){
        this.isVisible(false)
    };
}

var vm = function() {
    this.first = new hiddenModel('Show first', 'hidden content first');
    this.second = new hiddenModel('Show second', 'hidden content second');
};
```

*Note: for just these two elements this might be too much overhead but as soon as you need more hidden items, it pays off. Any additional element needs just one short line of HTML and JS each.*

### UPDATE FOR COMPLEX TEMPLATE WITH BINDINGS:

If your HTML content contains bindings itself you can put it into templates too and load these dynamically

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xA9RU/)

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'hidden-template', data: first }"></div>
<script type="text/html" id="content-first">
    test simple content
</script>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'hidden-template', data: second }"></div>
<script type="text/html" id="content-second">
    test content <a href="#" data-bind="click:testBtn">with binding</a>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="hidden-template">
    <a data-bind="click: showHidden, visible: isVisible, text : linkText" href="#"></a>
    <div data-bind="visible: !isVisible(), template: { name: content, data: $parent }" style="display:none"></div>
</script>
```

**JS**

```
var hiddenModel = function(linkText, content) {
    this.linkText = linkText;
    this.content = content;
    this.isVisible = ko.observable(true);
    this.showHidden = function(){
        this.isVisible(false)
    };
}

var vm = function() {
    this.testBtn = function(){alert('it works');}
    this.first = new hiddenModel('Show first', 'content-first');
    this.second = new hiddenModel('Show second', 'content-second');
};
```

`content` is now the template id instead of an HTML string.

Comment: In my production example `div` with content is too complex (a lot of html with KO bindings) to put it into function constructor.

Comment: Any thoughts how to make it via `data-bind="visibilityDependsOn: anotherValue"` and `data-bind="visibilityTarget: someName"`? I really appreciate your suggestions, and trying to play with them.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an observableArray with some ids (one for each checkbox)?

You could then have methods like:

```
model hideElement = function(id) {
  model.hiddenElements.push(id);
}

model.showElement = function(id) {
  model.hiddenElements.remove(id);
}
```

And in your binding:

```
<div data-bind="click: function() { hideElement('two') }, visible: !hiddenElements().contains('one')"></div>
```

**Edit**: i updated your fiddle to show a possible implementations: http://jsfiddle.net/brCT9/4/

Comment: I think this is the way we need go, but make it more declarative via bindings. But how?